# Setting state in getDetails() occurs infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    this.state = {
  data: [],
  details: []
```

}

```
     componentDidMount() {
this.getDetails()
this.getCountries()
```

}

```
getCountries() {
Utils.rest('POST', 'https:///api-spot-get-all', {
  country: '',
  windProbability: ''
}).then(async (r) => {
  const data = await r.json();
  this.setState({
    data: data.result
  })
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

}

```
`getDetails() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let details_list = [];
  this.state.data.map(item => {
    return (
      Utils.rest('POST', 'https:///api-spot-get-details', {
        spotId: item.id
      })
      .then(async (r) => {
        const details_item = await r.json()
console.log(`Loaded ${details_list.length} item ...(of ${this.state.data.length})`);
        if (details_list.length === this.state.data.length) {
          await resolve(details_list)
        }
        details_list.push(details_item.result);
      })
    );
  })
})
```

}`

```
 render() {
```

return (
       {
        this.state.data.map((item, key) => {
          return (
            
            {item.id}
            {item.id}
            
          );
        })
      }

**Here is my code. After first call I am receiving id and passing it as input to second call**

Comment: please post the code instead of an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS fetch causes infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53136027/reactjs-fetch-causes-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is happening because you're calling `this.getCountries()` in the `render` function. So the function is called in every render, that causes a new request that sets a new state, which will trigger a new render an so on, creating an infinite loop. So, if you delete the function calling from the `render` function it should work.

Comment: If I delete this.getCountries() from render, I am unable to map data from this.getCountries(). How do I can handle it?
PS. I am a new in React and sorry for bad English. Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't it being called on `componentDidMount()`? There's where it's supposed to be called.

Comment: Yes, I called it in componentDidMount, but still no idea how to extract data from it and pass them to table?

Comment: I'll put this answer on a separate answer, because this hasn't proper formatting and has character limits.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const  myarray=[1,2,3,4,5]

  const mytable=myarray.map((item,key)=>{return(
    <table key={key}> 
      <tr><td>id</td><td>{item}</td></tr>
    </table>)
    })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {mytable}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can create a const in the render and use after in return so you can tryin your code to do something like that:

```
render() {
        const myComponent=  this.state.data.map((item, key) => { return (
                     <div key={key}>
                          <span>{item.it}</span>
                     </div>
                    ) });
        return (
          {myComponent}
        ) 
  }
```

I used  and is just for example you can use what structor you want as in the first example I used table...

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are calling `getDetails` method in `render`. render is not a good place to add methods which modify the internal state. please check the react [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of strange things there. First of all, `getDetails` returns a Promise, but the promise is not resolved anywhere. Its usage should be something like:

```
getDetails()
.then(data => {
  // do something with the data
}, error => {
  // manage here the error
}):
```

Also, `this.state.data.map` should be `this.state.data.forEach` and delete the `return` from inside, because you don't need to return anything outside

On the other hand, there's an issue with `getCountries`. Its name sais it's a GET, but the API call sends a POST.

After that's clarified, inside `getDetails` you're using the data retrieved in `getCountries`, so its call should be inside the request resolving inside `getCountries` or either change `getCountries` to a Promise and do something like:

```
this.getCountries()
.then(data => {
  this.getDetails();
});
```

You don't care when the `getDetails` call ends, so it doesn't need to return a Promise.

And, in the end, the `render` function should look more like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.data.map((item, key) =>
        <div key={key}>{item.id} - {item.id}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

After this it should work properly, more or less. I have to warn you, though. Probably you would need to do something easier to become familiar with React's flow and how to properly work with state and JS's asynchronous functions.